# What is the correct way to get glyphicons.css?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am using bootstrap 4.0. The [4.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/) documentation doesn't mention icons but the [3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) documentation does. I want to have an icon button similar to this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

I got that from the 3.3 documentation but it doesn't work. I did google for a solution ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245575/bootstrap-3-unable-to-display-glyphicon-properly), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036596/bootstrap-glyphicons-are-missing), etc.) and the way to do it seems to be to manually list a file like this:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Unfortunately I can't find one for version 4.0 but I wouldn't want to add it like that anyways without knowing what is going on. Why isn't it included in the link to the cdn on bootstraps homepage? I get the feeling you are supposed to serve this file yourself? But I downloaded bootstrap and it's not in there anyhow.

[image]

What am I missing? I want buttons with icons.

Comment: Why not use fontawesome http://fontawesome.io/

Comment: See the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components), they do cover the removal of icons Bootstrap 4. So use whatever makes sense. And if you only need a few icons look into something like [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) or [Fontello](http://fontello.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Font Awesome its AWESOME!!

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
        <span class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
```

That should work pretty fine.

Here is the list of all icons: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Good Luck!

Comment: I like font awesome as much as the next guy but I have issues. Issue 1, is that the bootstrap approved way of doing it? Issue 2, I literally need like one or two icons. I'd hate to add all that just for a few measly icons. Issue 3, the versions still don't match up ಠ_ಠ